# Can I get the IE version number and update number like this 11.0.9600?

Tags: javascript

Hi all thanks to help me,
I need to know all version number of internet explorer using java script, I need this because my site need to support a component that MS fix and for instance in this IE build number 11.0.9600 I not get that feature but in 11.0.9700 yes, so my website have to know about that.

This can be possible using javascript?

Comment: Using feature detection is generally a better approach than browser version detection - what is it that got fixed, can you code to check to look for something specific instead?

Comment: Use modernizr(https://modernizr.com/). Now IE uses Mozilla Engine internally. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh869301(v=vs.85))

Answer (score 1):

As James Thorpe already mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574731/can-i-get-the-ie-version-number-and-update-number-like-this-11-0-9600#comment95947203_54574731), browser (version) detection is not a good idea. In many ways.

First of all there is the question about privacy of your visitors. You shouldn't detect more than absolutely necessary. Anyone can set the information about his browser anyway to whatever he wants. So it is also less than reliable. A good and secure setup for browsing anonymously will not reveal browser version informations. You could say of course, someone using IE ... but let's not open that can of worms.

**The better way is feature detection.**

> The idea behind feature detection is that you can run a test to
>   determine whether a feature is supported in the current browser, and
>   then conditionally run code to provide an acceptable experience both
>   in browsers that do support the feature, and browser that don't.

If - for example - you want to know if your visitors browser supports HTML5 Canvas, you can create an element in memory and then check if a property exists on it.

```
function supports_canvas() {
  return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
}

if(supports_canvas()) { ... }
```

Your can learn about feature detection [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) where the quote and the example comes from.